# Suddenly grunt build fails

Tags: build, gruntjs, npm, dependencies, grunt-contrib-uglify

I was used to `grunt build` task to complete successfully, but since I merged my project edits with some of another developer colleague, it suddenly fails with an error I've never seen before:

```
grunt build
Loading "imagemin.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'process-nextick-args'
Loading "cdnify.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'abbrev'
Loading "grunt-karma.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'uglify-js'

Running "clean:dist" (clean) task
>> 0 paths cleaned.

Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task
Warning: Cannot find module './lang/clone' Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2015-09-25 09:44:30 UTC)
wiredep:app  31ms
Total 31ms
```

In the Gruntfile.js I commented `imagemin` and `cdnify` out in `concurrent:dist` and `build` tasks.

> **What have I done wrong?**

Here there are some informations about the version of the stuff I'm using:

```
node -v && npm -v && grunt --version
v0.10.35
2.1.1
grunt-cli v0.1.13
grunt v0.4.5
```

Moreover, I tried to run an `npm install` before the `grunt build`, but I have these warnings I've never seen before, except the very three ones:

```
npm WARN package.json rwui@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json rwui@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json rwui@0.0.0 No README data
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\gesposito\Documents\Developer\Software\Production\reportmed\api_ui\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\glob-watcher\node_modules\gaze\node_modules\globule\node_modules\glob requires graceful-fs@'~1.2.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\gesposito\Documents\Developer\Software\Production\reportmed\api_ui\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\vinyl-fs\node_modules\graceful-fs,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 3.0.8
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\gesposito\Documents\Developer\Software\Production\reportmed\api_ui\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-gifsicle\node_modules\gifsicle\node_modules\bin-build\node_modules\download\node_modules\gulp-decompress\node_modules\gulp-util requires object-assign@'^3.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\gesposito\Documents\Developer\Software\Production\reportmed\api_ui\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-gifsicle\node_modules\gifsicle\node_modules\bin-build\node_modules\download\node_modules\object-assign,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 4.0.1
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\gesposito\Documents\Developer\Software\Production\reportmed\api_ui\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-gifsicle\node_modules\gifsicle\node_modules\bin-wrapper\node_modules\download\node_modules\gulp-decompress\node_modules\gulp-util requires object-assign@'^3.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\gesposito\Documents\Developer\Software\Production\reportmed\api_ui\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-gifsicle\node_modules\gifsicle\node_modules\bin-wrapper\node_modules\download\node_modules\object-assign,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 4.0.1
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\gesposito\Documents\Developer\Software\Production\reportmed\api_ui\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-jpegtran\node_modules\jpegtran-bin\node_modules\bin-build\node_modules\download\node_modules\gulp-decompress\node_modules\gulp-util requires object-assign@'^3.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\gesposito\Documents\Developer\Software\Production\reportmed\api_ui\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-jpegtran\node_modules\jpegtran-bin\node_modules\bin-build\node_modules\download\node_modules\object-assign,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 4.0.1
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\gesposito\Documents\Developer\Software\Production\reportmed\api_ui\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-jpegtran\node_modules\jpegtran-bin\node_modules\bin-wrapper\node_modules\download\node_modules\gulp-decompress\node_modules\gulp-util requires object-assign@'^3.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\gesposito\Documents\Developer\Software\Production\reportmed\api_ui\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-jpegtran\node_modules\jpegtran-bin\node_modules\bin-wrapper\node_modules\download\node_modules\object-assign,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 4.0.1
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\gesposito\Documents\Developer\Software\Production\reportmed\api_ui\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-optipng\node_modules\optipng-bin\node_modules\bin-build\node_modules\download\node_modules\gulp-decompress\node_modules\gulp-util requires object-assign@'^3.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\gesposito\Documents\Developer\Software\Production\reportmed\api_ui\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-optipng\node_modules\optipng-bin\node_modules\bin-build\node_modules\download\node_modules\object-assign,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 4.0.1
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\gesposito\Documents\Developer\Software\Production\reportmed\api_ui\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-optipng\node_modules\optipng-bin\node_modules\bin-wrapper\node_modules\download\node_modules\gulp-decompress\node_modules\gulp-util requires object-assign@'^3.0.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\gesposito\Documents\Developer\Software\Production\reportmed\api_ui\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\imagemin\node_modules\imagemin-optipng\node_modules\optipng-bin\node_modules\bin-wrapper\node_modules\download\node_modules\object-assign,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 4.0.1
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\gesposito\Documents\Developer\Software\Production\reportmed\api_ui\node_modules\grunt-google-cdn\node_modules\bower\node_modules\inquirer\node_modules\chalk\node_modules\has-ansi requires ansi-regex@'^0.2.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\gesposito\Documents\Developer\Software\Production\reportmed\api_ui\node_modules\grunt-google-cdn\node_modules\bower\node_modules\inquirer\node_modules\ansi-regex,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.1.1
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\gesposito\Documents\Developer\Software\Production\reportmed\api_ui\node_modules\grunt-google-cdn\node_modules\bower\node_modules\inquirer\node_modules\chalk\node_modules\strip-ansi requires ansi-regex@'^0.2.1' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\gesposito\Documents\Developer\Software\Production\reportmed\api_ui\node_modules\grunt-google-cdn\node_modules\bower\node_modules\inquirer\node_modules\ansi-regex,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 1.1.1
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\gesposito\Documents\Developer\Software\Production\reportmed\api_ui\node_modules\grunt-google-cdn\node_modules\google-cdn\node_modules\bower requires chalk@'0.5.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency C:\Users\gesposito\Documents\Developer\Software\Production\reportmed\api_ui\node_modules\grunt-google-cdn\node_modules\chalk,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version 0.5.1
```

> **EDIT**

I leave here the relevant parts of my `package.json`:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "^2.1.0",
    "grunt-concurrent": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.11.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "^0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-filerev": "^2.1.2",
    "grunt-google-cdn": "^0.4.3",
    "grunt-karma": "^0.10.1",
    "grunt-newer": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "^0.8.0",
    "grunt-svgmin": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "^3.0.0",
    "grunt-wiredep": "^2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.2.0",
    "jshint-stylish": "^1.0.0",
    "karma": "^0.12.31",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.1.8",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.5",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.1.4",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^2.0.0",
    "time-grunt": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test"
  }
```

> **EDIT**

Keep in mind that my colleague's `package.json` doesn't show any difference from mine.

Comment: Are the 3 tasks in error (imagemin, cdnify, grunt-karma) listed in your package.json?

Comment: I'm actually having the same issue, tried pulling down a project, did npm install / bower install, and it won't run at all...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you have outdated/mixed npm modules - did you merge `your node_modules` folder with your colleagues?

Anyway, I suggest deleting your local node_modules directory then re-running `npm install`.

Once you're stable again, the proper workflow should be:

- `node_modules` should be out of source control
- when you first get the project, run `npm install` to setup your local `node_modules`
- then you only need to touch it when `package.json` changes
- in that case, you run `npm update` to install the new versions locally

Comment: If I delete `node_modules` it looks like everything works, but this means that I have to delete and generate the `node_modules` from  scratch before each build, which is a waste of time and resources.

How can I tell to npm to install just the modules from my merge which are in conflict with the ones of my colleague (this should solve the conflicts in my favor, right?)?

Comment: `node_modules` only change when your `package.json` changes, and when it happens you can ask npm to only update what's changes. I edited my answer with the proper workflow.

Comment: Thing is, package.json only lists minimum versions, so even if it did not change, but your colleague did an npm update and got more recent versions in node_modules, and then you merged this with yours, anything can happen. That's why you should not merge node_modules. If your problem is solved, could you close the question?

Answer (score 0):

execute `install grunt-google-cd@0.3.0`

install version 0.3.0 there are components that are not in more updated versions